# Checkout an older commit and create a new master branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

As it seems, the `master` branch of one of my project's went into a completely wrong direction. So what I want to do is:

- Checkout an older commit
- Develop things into a different direction using a new branch
- Call this new branch `master` and discontinue the old `master` branch

How do I do this?

I have seen that I could create a new branch `branch1` and then use

```
$ git branch -m master old_master
$ git branch -m branch1 master
```

to backup the old `master` and then rename the new branch to `master`, but I wonder whether there are any drawbacks in this, and whether there is a better way to achieve my goal (whatever "better" means in this context).

Any thoughts or hints?

PS: The changes I want to "revert" have already been pushed, so I can not just delete them.

Comment: The approach you tell is really the good one. Using hard reset is also ok, if you open to loosing the development history till that point.

Comment: @mu無 If you turn this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you tell is really the good one. Using hard reset is ok only if you are open to loosing the development history till that point.

Basically, do the following

```
git branch -m master old_master
git branch -m branch1 master
```

After you've done it, you will need to force push the master (because your local branch history would be completely different from that on the remote)

```
git push -f origin master
```

Also note that in case there are multiple developers working on the master branch, their local master branch might be corrupted if they do a pull, so its best they re-create master branch on their machines.

```
git branch -D master
git branch master --track origin/master
```

Both the forced push and (possibly) recreating the master branch will be needed with with hard reset as well.

Answer (score 1):

1.You have to reset hard  on your master branch to the sha-id you want to rollback to

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

2. While doing the push, you would have to use the -f option

You can also try to do a **git revert** instead of git reset

PS: if you want to keep the history around , you can tag master branch with a tag name  or even create a branch named master_old